# How can I scroll down a page in jQuery within 14 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create an advertisement for my page. For this I want to make a screen record on my mobile phone with remote debugging opened. When I start the screen record, I want to paste a code in the debugging console that scrolls down the page for exact 14 seconds. I've found this here but this scrolls just up:

```
jQuery( "html, body" ).animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, "slow" );
```

So is there a simple solution for this? I can scroll with my finger via touch but this would look not very professional.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: you mean something like this? `jQuery( "html, body" ).animate( { scrollBottom: 0 }, "slow", 14000 );`

Comment: From a UX perspective, I feel like this would make me leave your site - though I get that it's a demo, I just hope it never makes it into a production system.

Comment: Did you read my response? I get that this is for a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollTop: 0` means "scroll to 0px from the top". You want the bottom:

```
jQuery( "html, body" ).animate( { scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 13000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interval

```js
setTimeout(function(){
jQuery( "html, body" ).animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, "slow" );
console.log(14);
}, 14000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can also use

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery("div#scrol").scrollTop(jQuery("div#scrol")[0].scrollHeight);
}, 14000);
```

```html
<div id='scrol'></div> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```